# How to exclude downloads using edd_store_discount function for easy digital downloads plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm setting up custom discount code generator via API and I got everything working except one thing. I got no idea how to exclude certain products/downloads using edd_store_discount function. Wordpress and EDD plugin are up to date and I'm using 7.3.8 php version. Just in case you need that info.

My biggest problem is I'm not quite sure whats the field name and how the IDs should be saved for excluded downloads field. I googled as much as I could but there were no solutions. Most of the code was c/p from a guide I found but it has no mention of excluding products either.

```php
add_filter("wcra_zapier_callback" , "wcra_zapier_callback_handler");            
function wcra_zapier_callback_handler($param){  

$sendemail = $param['email']; //Grab email from post request
$email = sanitize_email( urldecode( $sendemail ) ); //sanitize it just in case
$parts = explode('@', $email); //split the email
$email = $parts[0]; //use only first part of email, before @
$email = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $email); //leave only alpha-numeric characters

    //Create random discount code
    function generateRandomString($length = 5) {
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
    }
    $rcode = generateRandomString();
    $code = $email."-".$rcode;
    //Set expiration time -- 604800 == week in seconds
    $expires = time() + ( 1 * 604800 );
    //create code and get it's ID
    $details = array(
        'code'              => $code,
        'name'              => $email,
        'status'            => 'active',
        'is_single_use'     => 1,
    //  'excluded-products[]' => array(23756,23705),  This is the one thats bothering me, I tried switching up names and values but had no luck
        'amount'            => '100',
        'expiration'        => date( 'm/d/Y H:i:s', $expires ),
        'type'              => 'percent',
        'max' => 1,
        'uses' => 0
    );
    $id = edd_store_discount( $details, null );

     //Check for error
    if( ! is_numeric( $id ) ){
        wp_send_json_error( ['error' => 'Failed to create discount' ] );
    }
    //get discount code
    $discount_code = edd_get_discount_code( $id );

//Send emai
//user posted variables

  $ademail = get_option('admin_email');
  $message = "Hello, your special discount code is: \"".$discount_code."\"\r\n";

//php mailer variables
  $to = $sendemail;
  $subject = "Discount code you requested";
  $headers = 'From: '. $ademail . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $ademail . "\r\n";


//Here put your Validation and send mail
$sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
      if($sent) {
        $mailstatus = "sent";
      }//message sent!
      else  {
        $mailstatus = "failed";
      }//message wasn't sent




return $discount_code;  
}
```

I wish to define a static list of 6 products/downloads that will be excluded from this discount code.Exactly like its possible from admin dashboard
https://puu.sh/E7H1D.png (can't embed cause of my low rep)

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is probably late but i'll just put it out there just in case anyone else is struggling with the same issue.

To exclude given products, add them as an array with key 
`excluded-products => array($productId1, $productId2, ...)` as shown below:

```
$details = array(
        'code' => 'YOUR-CODE,
        'name' => 'DISCOUNT NAME',
        'status' => 'active',
        'is_single_use' => 1,
        'amount' => '20',
        'type' => 'percent',
        'max' => 1,
        'uses' => 0,
        'not_global'=>1,
        'product_condition'=>'all',

         //an array of sample product ids to exclude
        'excluded-products'=>array(5160,5130,3000),

        'products'=>array(5158) //products that must be included
    );
```